Filling the gaps in an OEIS sequence
In my recent thread, I asked for help with finding a formula for a sequence. Gladly, some very nice people here helped me find the formula that I've been looking for, so I'm trying my luck once again.
The sequence OEIS A030109 naturally forms blocks of length $2^$. I would like to create new sequences of  elements that fill the gaps between blocks $2^$ and $2^{+1}$.
I’ve observed that for a given $2^{+1}$, you can follow a recursive process:

Remove the last element from the sequence.
Iterate over the remaining elements.
If the value of an element is greater than the value of the removed element, subtract 1 from that element’s value.

Example:
For the block where =3, the bit-reversed sequence is: [0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7]
N=7: [0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3]
N=6: [0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4]
N=5: [0, 3, 2, 4, 1]
N=4: [0, 2, 1, 3] (=2)

While this approach provides the desired result, calculating the -element sequence requires computing sequences for +1, +2, and so on. To avoid this, I’d like to derive a formula that directly calculates these sequences. So far I had no luck in doing so.
Thank you in advance!

Close but not quite exactly right, but too long for a comment:
Let $(s_j)=(0,\frac12,\frac14,\frac34,\frac18,\frac58,\frac38,\frac78,\frac{1}{16},\frac{9}{16},\frac{5}{16},\frac{13}{16},\frac{3}{16},\frac{11}{16},\frac{7}{16},\frac{15}{16},\ldots)$ be the sequence whose initial block of length $2^k$ equals [the OEIS-A030109 block of length $2^k$] divided by $2^k$. (These initial blocks of $(s_j)$ are all contained in one another, but the values are consistent as we increase $k$ to find more terms.)
Let $a_{N,j}$ ($1\le j\le N$) denote the $j$th element in the $N$th block as defined by the OP, so that $a_{8,7} = a_{7,7} = a_{6,2} = a_{5,2} = a_{4,4} = 3$ for example.
Then for a fixed $j$, the sequence $(a_{N,j})_{N=j}^\infty$ increases roughly linearly in $N$ with slope $s_j$. More precisely, $a_{N,j} - s_jN$ is a periodic function whose period is the denominator of $s_j$ (namely $2^{\lceil \log_2 j\rceil}$).
It's almost exactly the case that
$$
a_{N,j} = \lceil s_j N \rceil \quad (1\le j\le N),
$$
but occasionally $a_{N,j}$ exceeds $\lceil s_j N \rceil$; somehow $a_{N,j}$ groups together the increase-by-$1$s and stay-the-sames in each column a little more than $\lceil s_j N \rceil$ does.

Thanks for giving me the refined understanding of the problem I provided and exploring an alternative process. Your solution indeed gets close, but not quite enough. It’s surprising to me that it works perfectly for some sequences of N. Maybe that’s something for me to explore.
